# "Linked" section overlapping divider

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

At [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20473`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20473), the "Linked" section on the right currently overlaps the decorative divider.

[image: (screenshot)]

Comment: I see this too.

Comment: Here too http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20414/759

Comment: i'm looking into this.

Comment: Here too: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28024

Answer (score 2):

I added extra padding on the bottom. The fix will be on the live server after our next production build(within 24hrs).

Comment: In the 3 examples in the links above, there definitely is more padding, but still a little squished for two of them IMO.